# Simple Log regression model in R

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to fit a regression model, as the plot says the relation is log.

[image]

I tried to use

```
lm(logData$x ~ logData$b3, data = logData)
```

but it did not work because it fits the linear model.

Also I tried to use

```
model = nls(logData$x ~ logData$b3)
```

but it gives me errors.

So, what I need to do is fit the simple log regression also plot the regression curve on the scatter plot.

Comment: did you tried to convert your data in order to get the linear correlation?

Comment: No I did not, is it better to convert it be linear or to fit a nonlinear model? because I am fitting a polynomial regression as well on another data and I did that without converting it by using lm(y~ ploly(x, 2, raw=T), data=data)

Comment: Why choose the polynomial regression when your data shows log relation?

Comment: I think this could be the good example for your case: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/log_transformed_regression.htm

Comment: Thanks, I mean I applied polynomial regression on another data not this data

Comment: Also please, I need to plot a curve line on the above plot, is that possible?

Comment: I think it would helpful to reverse the transformations here so that people can suggest another relationship. It's not a good starting point to see that two logged variables are themselves nonlinearly related. Can you post the raw data? (I am treating this as a statistical question despite the phrasing in R code terms.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my opinion, it's a good strategy to transform your data before performing linear regression model as your data show good log relation:

```
> #generating the data
> n=500
> x <- 1:n
> set.seed(10)
> y <- 1*log(x)-6+rnorm(n)
> 
> #plot the data
> plot(y~x)
> 
> #fit log model
> fit <- lm(y~log(x))
> #Results of the model
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ log(x))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.06157 -0.69437 -0.00174  0.76330  2.63033 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -6.4699     0.2471  -26.19   <2e-16 ***
log(x)        1.0879     0.0465   23.39   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.014 on 498 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5236,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5226 
F-statistic: 547.3 on 1 and 498 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

>
> coef(fit)
(Intercept)      log(x) 
  -6.469869    1.087886 
> 
> #plot 
> x=seq(from=1,to=n,length.out=1000)
> y=predict(fit,newdata=list(x=seq(from=1,to=n,length.out=1000)),
+           interval="confidence")
> matlines(x,y,lwd=2)
```

Results of the previous code:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Xuan, thats what I really need. I appreciate your kind help, also other people

Comment: you need also to check the goodness of the model on your own data as you didn't attach it here!

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to the question. You (approximately) found the relationship you invented in the first place. But you are not analysing the OP's data (which appear not yet to be available) and not addressing the strong implication in the column names used that the OP's variables are **already transformed**.

Comment: To check the goodness of fit i think R^2 is the right criterion, I just applied what you mentioned and it does work, R^2=.88 which is great. The only thing did not work yet is the last commands to plot the curve, it might be because my sample size is 300 #plot 
> x=seq(from=1,to=n,length.out=1000)
> y=predict(fit,newdata=list(x=seq(from=1,to=n,length.out=1000)),
+           interval="confidence")
> matlines(x,y,lwd=2)

Comment: @Memo: you need to write nrow(logData) instead of n in the code

Comment: @NickCox The goal is not to find the relationship that we invented a priori. Because the question owner doesn't provide data, the only solution that I see is to simulate the data having more or less the same form as the only graph provided. Then fit the linear regression to the data log-transformed based on the hypothsis that the relation is actually log. As the owner said, the model is good in term of $R^2$, I know that it's not the good measure of goodness of the model, but I didn't see any other solution without data provided.

Comment: The OP accepted your answer, so evidently found it helpful, but I don't see exactly how it helps. Working with log log would be fraught with problems.